# Either type A or B in rust

Tags: rust

A have a struct with attributes that could have different types

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct A {
    pub foo: B | C
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct B {
    pub bar: usize
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct C {
    pub bar2: usize
}
```

Is it possible in rust to achieve something like `pub foo: B | C`, so the type will be determined on runtime?

Comment: You mean an [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) ?

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't find a solution for getting the value. `a.foo.bar` or `a.foo.unwrap().bar` or with casting did not work. Do you know how to get the value?

Comment: @chocolatecake are they the same type both `foo.bar`? Anyway, just `match` foo.

Comment: Some are the same, some aren't. 
`Match` worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible in rust to achieve something like pub foo: B | C, so the type will be determined on runtime?

The way to do this in Rust is with an [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) storing items of either:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub enum A {
    B(B),
    C(C)
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct B {
    pub bar: usize
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct C {
    pub bar2: usize
}
```

Here `A` can have one of two values: `A::B` which *contains* a value of type `B` (in a way similar to single-member [tuple structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs)) or `A::C` which contains a value of type `C`. `A::B` and `B` should not be confused: the former is essentially a function while the latter is a type.

The basest way to get values out of enums is [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/match.html#matching-on-enums):

```rust
fn foo(a: A) {
    match a {
        A::B(b) => println!("Got a B: {:?}", b),
        A::C(c) => println!("Got a C: {:?}", c)
    }
}
```

Since Rust enums are completely standard types you can also add utility methods to them, that is exactly how e.g. `Option` and `Result` work e.g.

```rust
impl A {
    fn b(&self) -> Option<&B> {
        if let A::B(b) = self { Some(b) } else { None }
    }
    fn c(&self) -> Option<&C> {
        if let A::C(c) = self { Some(c) } else { None }
    }
}

fn bar(a: A) {
    if a.b().is_some() {
        println!("Got a B!");
    } else {
        println!("Got a C :(");
    }
}
```

Now since you are deriving `Serialize` and `Deserialize` with this I assume you're also interfacing with an external system e.g. typescript or whatever.

In that case you will almost certainly have to customise the [serialisation scheme](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html) of the enum: serde's default is external tagging which in my experience is never what you're looking for, because it's really not a scheme other languages tend to use for their (formal or informal) unions.

Internal tagging and untagged are much more common, with the odd adjacent tagging once in a (rare) while.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an enum, then you'll have to `if let` or `match` on different variants of it, other solutions like "unwraping" are practically unsafe. You have a lot of options to retrieve the value, depending on your style / complexity of access

Example:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub enum BorC {
    B(B),
    C(C),
} 

// or maybe simpler without defining `struct B` and `struct C`
//#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
//pub enum BorC {
//    B(usize),
//    C(usize),
//} 

// ...

fn main() {
    let my_val: BorC = BorC::B(B{bar: 5});
    if let BorC::B(B{bar}) = &my_val {
        println!("1) B::bar = {}", bar);
    }
    if let BorC::B(b) = &my_val {
        println!("2) B::bar = {}", b.bar);
    }
    match &my_val {
        BorC::B(B{bar}) => println!("3) B::bar = {}", bar),
        BorC::C(C{bar2}) => println!("3) C::bar2 = {}", bar2),
    }
    match &my_val {
        BorC::B(b) => println!("4) B::bar = {}", b.bar),
        BorC::C(c) => println!("4) C::bar2 = {}", c.bar2),
    }
}

// prints:
// 1) B::bar = 5
// 2) B::bar = 5
// 3) B::bar = 5
// 4) B::bar = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, `enum` is the way to go.

For your use case of "one of two variants", you might consider the [`either` crate](https://docs.rs/either/1.6.1/either/), that already offers `Serialize` and `Deserialize` (as well as other useful traits).